# Testing Meteor with Velocity at Codeship

Tags: meteor, jasmine-node, codeship, meteor-velocity

I'm trying to configure a CI infrastructure at Codeship. My local `meteor --test` command works like charm, but I'm getting a weird error at Codeship.

**Local:**

```
I20141208-12:29:42.602(2)? Started
I20141208-12:29:42.602(2)? .
I20141208-12:29:42.603(2)? 
I20141208-12:29:42.603(2)? 1 spec, 0 failures
I20141208-12:29:42.603(2)? Finished in 0.014 seconds
PASSED jasmine-server-unit : Job => Job should be created with title, description, location and isRemote
```

**Codeship:**

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While Building the application:
node_modules/velocity-cli/velocity-cli.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

**Setup commands:**

```
curl -o meteor_install_script.sh https://install.meteor.com/
chmod +x meteor_install_script.sh
sed -i "s/type sudo >\/dev\/null 2>&1/\ false /g" meteor_install_script.sh
./meteor_install_script.sh
```

**Test commands:**

```
meteor --test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahoy,

*velocity-cli* needs to be install globally. Could you add the following command to your setup steps before you call the *meteor* executable?

`npm install -g velocity-cli`

*Disclaimer: I'm working for Codeship*

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
meteor run --test
```

command? This is what [velocity-cli](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity-ci) creators are telling to do now.

Comment: are you sure the question still requires the answer? "asked Dec 8 '14"

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the setup commands from the OP to the following :

```
curl -o meteor_install_script.sh https://install.meteor.com/
chmod +x meteor_install_script.sh
sed -i "s/type sudo >\/dev\/null 2>&1/\ false /g" meteor_install_script.sh
./meteor_install_script.sh
export PATH=$HOME/.meteor:$PATH
npm install -g velocity-cli
```

Also, for what it's worth I am using cucumber instead of jasmine and this still applies.